# A normed space in which unit circle in convex

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Let $X$ be a normed linear space (real or complex). Consider $B = \{x \in X : \lVert x \rVert = 1\}.$ I want an example of a non-trivial normed space in which $B$ is a convex set.

I have proved that $B$ cannot be convex in inner product space. To see this, if $x,y \in $B then we see that $\lVert x  + y\rVert = 2$ using convexity. But if we take $x,y$ as elements which are orthonormal to each other in a inner product space, then $\lVert x  + y\rVert = \sqrt2.$
So all inner product spaces are ruled out. The sequence space $\ell^{\infty}$ also does not satisfy this condition.

Are there are any such spaces? If no such spaces exists then how do I prove?.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $\|x\|=1$ then $\|-x\|=1$ and $0=\|0\|=\|\frac {x +(-x)} 2\|\neq 1$ so $B$ can never be convex (except when the normed linear space space is $\{0\}$ in which case $B$ is empty, hence convex).